# I cant send eth from a smart contract to an address

Tags: solidity

Im trying to send eth from a smart contract to an address but it sends it from msg.sender to smart contract address.Here are my functions

```
receive() external payable {} 

function close(address payable _to) public payable   {
    _to.send(donated);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does send it from the contract to the `_to` address. If you are testing with a small amount of Wei, the cost of gas is most likely larger than the amount of ether that you receive, that is why it seems like the transaction goes the other way around.

Don't forget about the gas fee.